# Call model method in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

What's the easy way of calling model method in Yii2. Something like:

```
$a = User::model()->method();
```

Code like this:

```
$a = new User()->method();
```

don't work.

Answer (score 2):

This is the very basic thing.

Calling model method in both Yii1 and Yii2 is similar and done like that:

```
$model = new User();
$model->method();
```

Note that for Yii2 you also need to specify namespace of `User` class.

The method must be public obviously.

If you don't want use variable assignment, you need to place brackets differently:

```
(new User)->method();
```

and not:

```
new User()->method();
```

This is PHP language feature, it has nothing to do with Yii framework.

And as for your particular case - `model()` in Yii1 is used for constructing queries with `ActiveRecord`.

Replacement for Yii2 is `find()` method, you can read about it in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28563593/returns-the-static-model-of-the-specified-ar-class-in-yii-2-0).

Answer (score 1):

Since Yii 2.0.13 you can use [`instance()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-staticinstancetrait#instance()-detail) to get static instance of model. It works in similar way as [`model()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#model-detail) in Yii 1.1 - creates model object only once and reuses it for every call. It should be faster and more readable than `(new User())->method()`, which will create separate model on every call.

```
User::instance()->method();
User::instance()->getAttributeLabel('some_attribute');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can call a method as follows,

```
$a = new User();

$b = $a->method();
```

Answer (score -1):

Calling Model Method in any Where the application:

```
\app\model\ModelName::methodName();
\app\modules\ModuleName\models\ModelName::methodName();
```

Answer (score -1):

In yii2 you can call a method inside in a model as follows,

$a = Model::method();